# Static code analysis issue of Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type at file.SaveAs(filePath) in C# project

Tags: c#, file-upload, static-code-analysis

We have done static code analysis using Kiuwan tool for our C# project and we are stuck at "Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type" issue at "file.SaveAs(filePath)". We tried different ways to resolve it also the ways those are defined theoretically at https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/434.html . 
Any help from any of you is helpful.

```
var directoryPath =Path.Combine(DocumentManagementRootDirectory , 
dbFile.ID.ToString());
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
var path = Path.Combine(directoryPath , fName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

This is the code where we get this issue. We are not getting how to fix this one. 
This really sucks. May there is a simple fix for this but we are not getting that. 
Any help from all of you is appreciable.

Regards,

Comment: What is `fName`? I mean, where does it come from?

Comment: Its file name and its passed as HTTPRequest parameter to controller action.